# How to run php code in Twig template file

Tags: php, function, twig

I've tried to run a php code just like `<?php echo "Text" ?>` into Twig template file but it didn't work.

Anyway to executing php code in Twig file?

Comment: Why would you want to echo a string when you can do it without PHP?

Comment: Twig is a templating system, that's not his purpose

Comment: Solved! Thanks all <3